# Is data binding a feature of XAML? The Silverlight CLR? the C# language?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I'm learning Silverlight and am trying to ingest some new concepts. Just so I understand, is the data binding feature found in Silverlight part of Silverlight itself? Or is part of the underlying .NET framework itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is part of the Silverlight runtime (which includes the Silverlight version of the CLR).  You can set up bindings without using XAML (see BindingOperations.SetBinding) and you can set up bindings in Visual Basic or any other language that targets Silverlight and can call the SetBinding API.